Why is the TL431 considered highly stable?
The voltage of the TL431 variable voltage reference is set by a resistive voltage divider, so the output voltage of TL431 depends on the resistor values. When the temperature changes, the resistor values change. The output voltage of the TL431 must also change.
Why is the TL431 considered a highly stable precision reference since its output depends on resistors?

If you see a reason why the resistances should not change proportionally, please add that to your question

I recommend you have a look at these excellent design notes from Shuo Chen.

Why is the TL431 is considered a highly stable precision reference <-- can you provide some context as to who considers it highly stable and, under what circuit conditions and for what circuit topology?

The datasheet defines what a TL431 does and doesn't do. Usually :-). When used in variable mode the resistor performance is factored into what te datasheet tells you. SO what people consider about it is set by what they consider about what the data sheet says.

Just as a challenge: stability can also be used to say it doesn't oscillate irrespective of output capacitance or other factors. So it's not entirely clear if your source and you are thinking about the same kind of stability.

Since the feedback voltage depends on the RATIO of the two resistor values, and because the resistors are (assumed to be) of the same type and at the same temperature, the ratio will remain basically the same even if their values shift up or down due to temperature changes, but they shift by the same percentage of their individual values.
In summary, it's not their individual values that are utterly important but the ratio of their values, and that's why the set voltage is considered stable.

That assumption is just the sort of thing that should be obvious, but only is with a certain level of experience and the right frame of mind


Why is the TL431 is considered a highly stable precision reference since its output depends on resistors?

It is more stable than the simple Zener diode because it has an internal voltage reference and uses external negative feedback to control the output of an internal opamp.
Ideally, the resistors are of the same type and have the same temperature coefficient. In a voltage divider (used for feedback) their absolute value doesn't matter as much as their ratio. Use one metal film resistor and an old carbon based one and see the ratio also changing with temperature.
The datasheet shows some sources of uncertainty, and the reference input current is one of them:

So, the absolutes values also matter, by a tiny amount. With larger resistor values setting the output voltage to higher values than the reference, there is more sensitivity to reference input current:


A TL431 is about as bad as a voltage reference can be and still be called a reference. It has an initial tolerance of 3% to 0.5% and varies less than 1% over the full temperature range (in a parabolic fashion, with the highest slope at low temperatures- so quoting drift using the 'box' method is deceptive). It's a semi-precision part that is acceptable for things like power supplies that need an overall accuracy of better than 5%. Not bad for 1 to 5 pennies in quantity. In fact, a linear regulator with a light load will often have similar temperature stability.
You can buy ICs with matched and trimmed resistors on on the chip (for certain specific common output voltages) and a better circuit for temperature stability than the TL431 but it will cost more. You'll get much better initial tolerance as part of the package (some improved references are much more accurate and lower power, but drift with temperature about as much as the TL431 because they use the same band-gap principle).
There's about 7 orders of magnitude temperature stability ratio between TL431 and the best references available in standards labs (fewer than 100 such exist worldwide). By spending a lot more money than a TL431 costs you can get monolithic solutions off the shelf with around 2 orders of magnitude better stability.
So if you're building a power supply or making measurements where 1%-ish accuracy is okay, and don't mind spending 1mA and have enough supply voltage available, then the TL431 might be the right choice. There are scores of other choices out there, for good reason.
As far as depending on the ratio of resistors, that's usually true  in general for references. The resistors may be internal to the chip (so you pay for the internal trimmed metal film resistors along with the chip), or you may have to provide them externally or even trim or select them to get the voltage you want. You can buy precision networks with matched tempcos and precision trimmed ratios. The one I linked is ~1000x better than a TL431's inherent tempco- you'd not use a $30 resistor array on a few penny part but it might be the right choice for an ovenized buried zener reference.
There are at least a couple technologies that don't work that way - floating gate references and Josephson Junction references, however each has some drawbacks.
P.S. in the old days there were (there still are, but not designed in so much) temperature-compensated Zener reference diodes. They required circuit design (not just picking a couple resistors) since they needed to be run at a specific current such as 7.5mA +/-10uA (so, most likely bootstrapped since they also didn't regulate that well with current changes), only had one available but loosely specified voltage (6.2V +/-5% was standard, with 1% as special),  but they were way more stable with temperature than a TL431- single-digit ppm/K, and linear with T so no fudging of the slope in the specs. I have some old test equipment with 1N829A reference diodes and it has held its calibration well for many decades.

Perhaps we should define stability, in comparison to other methods of obtaining a fixed DC potential. If you use a 5V supply with a resistor potential divider to derive a +2.5V reference, for example, then any supply noise will be directly coupled into that reference.
Using a regular zener diode, you can obtain a reference potential more immune to power supply fluctuations than the potential divider, by an order of magnitude, but which will be somewhat temperature dependent.
The TL431 produces a potential that is perhaps another order of magnitude better than the zener diode in terms of supply rejection, while simultaneously having a far superior temperature coefficient.
The meaning of "highly stable" is subjective. The specifications of the TL431 in absolute terms aren't very meaningful, and there are shunt regulators and references available that far out-perform the TL431. In comparison to more primitive methods, though, it is strikingly superior, deserving of the accolade "highly stable", and it is more than adequate for many many applications.

Indeed, the voltage depends on resistors. And the resistor value depends on temperature.
The cheapest 10k 1% 0402 SMD resistor might have a temperature coefficient of +/- 200 ppm / °C. Over 100 degrees that's +/- 2% change. Typically the tempco is not even that large but 100ppm.
But you don't have to use the TL431 in a circuit that uses resistors.
The chip itself deviates about 6mV over whole temperature range. That's less than 0.3%.
So the chip is precise itself.
If you want to use the chip in a circuit with resistors, only then you need to consider the temperature coefficient of the resistors too. 25 ppm/°C resistors are not much more expensive if you need them.
And in the event you use the chip with resistors, you also need to consider using resistors with similar tempco, as nothing happens if both resistors change up by 2%, but if one resistor goes up by 1% and the other down by 1%, only then you start to see the effect of resistors to the output of the chip.

The best TL431 from TI (the B version) has an opening accuracy of 0.5% and a temperature coefficient of about 97 ppm / °C. Here's the datasheet if you want to check.

16 mV over 165 °C is 97 ppm / °C.
You can buy 0.1% resistors that have a temperature coefficient of 25 ppm / °C and, these are not considered exotic components. So, when you say this...

The voltage of the TL431 variable voltage reference is set by a
resistive voltage divider, so the output voltage of TL431 depends on
the resistor values. When the temperature changes, the resistor values change. The output voltage of the TL431 must also change.

...I believe you are missing a trick because the TL431B can drift all by itself (much worse on other grades) and isn't as accurate as decent resistors that will also likely act ratiometrically.

One of the alternatives to a TL431 is a low voltage Zener. Compared to a low voltage Zener, the TL431 IS highly stable and accurate. So when the TL431 was introduced, that was a big selling point. However, "highly stable" is a relative term, and for many uses, the TL431 (with or without a voltage divider to adjust output voltage) may not be stable or accurate enough. In this respect the claim "highly stable" (or "precision") is not much different from any other unquantified claim. It is essentially a marketing claim, designed to draw attention to the product, and as newer and more stable and accurate products enter the market, its value as a claim declines.


Why is the TL431 considered a highly stable precision reference since its output depends on resistors depends on resistor ratios?

(italicized text is mine)
Because any two decent resistors of the same type from the same manufacturer will keep their ratio, over a range of temperatures, much better than the TL431 will keep its voltage gain (!).
Resistors are worse at keeping their absolute resistance in face of temperature changes, and the cheapest ones will lose out to a TL431. That's why TL431's only depends on a ratio of resistances, not on an absolute resistance. That's a key design decision that made its performance possible.
